# flextable package assigns changes without <-

Tags: r, pipe, flextable

I'm not sure if this is the correct forum to post this, but I have noticed some strange behavior with the `flextable` package in R, and was wondering if anyone can shed any light.

In the [documentation](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/layout.html) for `flextable` it shows objects being modified when they are re-assigned to themselves, eg:

```
ft <- regulartable(head(iris)) 
ft <- color(ft, color = "orange", part = "body" )
```

However, my code is modifying the actual table even without re-assigning it, just using piping `%>%`:

```
myft <- regulartable(head(iris))
myft %>% align(j = 1, align = "left")
myft    # changed
```

I don't think piping is the issue as it doesn't have the same effect with other packages, eg:

```
library(plyr)
df <- head(iris)
df %>% mutate(Sum=Sepal.Width*2)
df    # unchanged
```

Is this a bug in `flextable`? Or is this by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that you can mutate formats without assigning the object. But that's not a behavior you can rely on. This is an unwanted design ;) and should be corrected in the next versions so it is safer to assign the result if you want your code to work with future versions.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :) We definitely don't want to change the base table without assigning, so hopfully the next release comes out soon :)

Comment: @RAB the new release is on CRAN now

Comment: Small issue, I no longer seem to be able to add colour or lines to my flextable... are `hline_bottom(border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 1)) %>%
  bg(bg = "red", i = 1, part = "body")` still the right commands to use?

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue. Is it only happening in the Windows RStudio viewer?

Comment: Is Windows RStudio Viewer just RStudio? Or is it a different program?

Comment: A colleague helped here. The viewer pane of RStudio on windows does not support color transparency encoded as `#AAAAAAFF`. It should work on usual navigators. I will correct soon